# What legal document is used for listing business partners or company directors?

Tags: business, colorado

My friend and I have registered an LLC for the purpose of running an e-commerce website. The registration form for Colorado business application did not ask to list company directors, nor did the EIN process.

Is there a legal document we can create that shows the company name, info, and the names of the partners involved? Otherwise, I'm thinking, there is no legal claim a partner can make in regards to company ownership, or decision making, or profit entitlements, etc.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need what's known as an **Operating Agreement**.  This has to be drafted in compliance with the laws and rules for LLCs proscribed by the state in which the LLC is domiciled.  Any business attorney should be able to draft (or refer you to an attorney who can draft) an Operating Agreement.  For typical multi-member LLCs without anything unusual this would be mostly "boilerplate."

Comment: Thank you very much, @feetwet, that gives me a research vector